# Hall effect current sensor ACS712 for battery application

Tags: adc, battery-charging, current-measurement, hall-effect, shunt

I want to measure the current of 12V lead acid battery for charger application. So mostly, I need bidirectional current sensing. The current measurement can be done using shunt resistor or using hall effect sensors. I see the shunt current sensors comes with I2C or SPI analog output.
But the ACS712 can be directly hooked up to the analog pin of MCU.

Do I need to use any op amps here to maintain the current gain?
Or just use ACS712 sensor hooked up directly to the battery terminals and sensor output terminals to the MCU?

Comment: (1) You might find the following Q&A useful: Rpi Current Sensing Using ACS712 and INA219
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94403/raspberry-pi-current-voltage-sensors-10a-rating-and-40v-respectively. (2) You need ADC, but no opAmp. (3) You need different current sensors for different test ranges.

Comment: If in case I need two measure four battery currents at a time with ADC of STM32. Now the ACS712 cannot be used instead we use INA219 using I2C. Is this operation possible. I feel I2C in STM32 is tough.

Comment: For battery charging applications, there are other current sense amplifiers with dedicate charging/discharging output signals, eg, CJMCU-4080 MAX4080SASA Current Sense Amplifier - €1.56
https://th.aliexpress.com/item/1005001355840165.html

Comment: I just need a suggestion that for measuring the battery voltage, we can directly use voltage divider or is it better to use voltage sensor.

Comment: Neither SPI or I2C are "analog".  they are both digital busses.

Answer (score 0):

ACS712 has 3 different types. These are 5A, 20A and 30Ampere versions. The sensitivities are 185 mv/A , 100mv/A and 66mV/A . Actually if these values are good for your system, just hook up the VIOut pin directly to MCU ADC input pin. Be sure VDD of ACS712 is same as VADC voltage  of MCU.[image]

If you need more you can use amplifier circuit for increase the sensitivity up to 610mV/A.

[image]